# ExtJs get widget component from widgetcolumn

Tags: extjs, components, component-query

I have components in a window. One of the are grid that first column is a widgetcolumn with checkbox widget. i don't have field in model for this column, this column is just in my view(Ext.grid.View).

My widgetcolumn

```
editGrid.columns.push({
            xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
            widget: {
                xtype: 'checkbox',
                listeners: {
                    change: function (checkbox, newValue) {
                        var checkedRecordId= checkbox.getWidgetRecord().getId();
                      //when checkbox click, add/remove record id in/from array.
                        if (newValue) {
                            editGrid.checkedEstimationIds.push(checkedRecordId);
                        } else {
                            Ext.Array.remove(editGrid.checkedEstimationIds, checkedRecordId);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

Between paging i want get checkbox column(widgetcolumn) and check them depend on array, my store and it's callback function:

```
editGrid.store.on('load', function (store, records) {
        // checked boxes depend on checkedArrayIds
        // how get check boxes???
        for (i in records) {
            if (Ext.Array.contains(editGrid.checkedEstimationIds, records[i].id)) {

                //var row = editGrid.getView().getRow(parseInt(i),)//doesn't work;
                var gridView = editGrid.getView()
                var checkboxes = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('checkbox',gridView);


            } 
        }

    });
```

I want get this column and check them depend of an array of ids. how get extjs checkboxes component? i try this but doesn't work:

```
var gridView = editGrid.getView()
var checkboxes = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('checkbox',gridView);
```

**update**

this get me widgetcolumn:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('widgetcolumn',editGrid)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found **onWidgetAttach(widget,record)**, in [forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?290124).(it's not documented in api document yet), so:

```
      editGrid.columns.push({
                xtype: 'widgetcolumn', 
                onWidgetAttach: function (widget, record) {
                if (Ext.Array.contains(editGrid.checkedEstimationIds, records)) {                   
                  widget.setValue(true);
                 }   
                },
            widget: {
                xtype: 'checkbox',
                listeners: {
                    change: function (checkbox, newValue) {
                        var checkedRecordId= checkbox.getWidgetRecord().getId();

                        if (newValue) {
                            editGrid.checkedEstimationIds.push(checkedRecordId);
                        } else {
                            Ext.Array.remove(editGrid.checkedEstimationIds, checkedRecordId);
                        }

                    }
                },
            }

        });
```